# In an API Blueprint document, can I combine a model with headers?

Tags: apiblueprint

The “model” facility seems intended to reduce duplication — when specifying the requests and responses to various methods on a resource, the same body will frequently be specified multiple times. So one can define a “model” and then “refer” to it within various request and response “payload” sections.

So I’ve defined a model like so:

```
### An Event

* Model (application/vnd.document+json)

            {
                "_type": "document",
                ...
            }
```

and I can then refer to it in various places:

```
* Response 200

    [An Event][]
```

which works great; the output includes the entire model body in place of the cross-reference.

However, I can’t figure out how to combine this reference with a request or response header.

I’ve tried various formats along these lines:

```
* Request

    * Headers

            If-Match: some-etag-value

    * Body

            [An Event][]
```

or

```
* Request

    * Headers

            If-Match: some-etag-value

    [An Event][]
```

with no luck.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to alter referenced model's payload. Neither it's planned in any of [API Blueprint Milestones](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues?labels=&milestone=&page=1&state=open).

Feel free to add it to the milestones and propose its syntax, if you will. Before doing so please consider any potential synergy with planned [API Blueprint Object Traits](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/47).